# Are Hardy spaces Banach algebras?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, hardy-spaces

Let $\mathbb D= \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. Let $Hol(\mathbb {D})$  denote the space of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb D$. The Hardy spaces on $\mathbb D$ are defined as follows.

$$H^p=\{f\in Hol(\mathbb {D}):\sup_{r<1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta}|^pd\theta<\infty\}\;\;\;(0<p<\infty),\\ \|f\|_p^p= \sup_{r<1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta}|^pd\theta ,$$

$$H^\infty=\{f\in Hol(\mathbb {D}):\sup_{z\in\mathbb D}|f(z)|<\infty\}, \|f\|_\infty = \sup_{z\in\mathbb D}|f(z)| .$$
I wanted to know if the above defined hardy spaces have a multiplication that is submultiplicative with the defined norms? Or if there is a text/ reference with the details?
This post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698057/is-the-p-norm-on-lp-submultiplicative) suggests that point wise  multiplication is submultiplicative.

Comment: I don't think that other post suggests what you suggest it suggests. The reason is that $\ell^p$ is very different, because if a $\nu$ is counting measure on $\Bbb N$ then $E\ne\emptyset$ implies $\nu(E)\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

Only $H^\infty$ is a Banach space under pointwise multiplication.  The trouble with the other $H^p$'s is that, for $f\in H^p$, you only have that $f^2\in H^p$ if $f\in H^{2p}$ and there are clearly counter examples to this.